# How can I add subsetting options as required by App user in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am interested in allowing the App user to drill down as far in the data as he/she wants. I made a toy example using the mtcars dataset below.

```
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("cyl", "Select cylinders:", unique(mtcars$cyl), multiple = T, selected = unique(mtcars$cyl)),
          selectInput("gear", "Select gears:", unique(mtcars$gear), multiple = T, selected = unique(mtcars$gear)),
          selectInput("am", "Select am:", unique(mtcars$am), multiple = T, selected = unique(mtcars$am)),
          numericInput("wt", "Select wt greater than:", value=1)
          , width = 2),
        
        mainPanel(
          
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(title = "Results", dataTableOutput("tAble"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
    
    , server = function(input, output, session){
      
      output$tAble <- renderDataTable({subset(mtcars, cyl %in% input$cyl & 
                                                gear%in%input$gear &
                                                am%in%input$am &
                                                wt > input$wt)})

      
    }
  )
)
```

This App will show the part of the data frame that meets all criteria.

**My issue here is that I have to write out all my potential subsetting criteria up front. What if my data has 200 potential variables on which to subset?
What I would like to be able to do is to have a method to add subsetting boxes as required without creating selectInputs/etc up front.**

For example, when the app starts up, show all data, then have an option to adding subsetting options by clicking on a button?

Comment: You need to use [dynamic UI](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html). Maybe this gist get you a start: https://gist.github.com/wch/4211337

Answer (score 0):

To render the UI elements you need to create a `tagList()` of UI elements in the server, and then render them in the UI.

Then you need to be able to subset your data based on the dynamically created UI elements. Here I'm evaluating a text string, based on the names of the UI elements, to do the subsetting

```
library(shiny)

runApp(
    list(
        ui = fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    uiOutput("myChoices"),
                    numericInput("wt", "Select wt greater than:", value=1)
                    , width = 2),

                mainPanel(

                    tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel(title = "Results", dataTableOutput("tAble"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )

        , server = function(input, output, session){

            myCols <- names(mtcars)[1:3]

            mySelectInputs <- tagList()

            for(i in myCols){
                mySelectInputs[[i]] <- selectInput(i, label = i, choices = unique(mtcars[, i]),
                                                                                     selected = unique(mtcars[, i]), multiple = T)
            }

            output$myChoices <- renderUI({
                mySelectInputs
            })

            output$tAble <- renderDataTable({

                lst <- sapply(myCols, function(x){
                    vals <- input[[x]]
                    substitute(x %in% i, list(i = vals, x = x))
                })

                txt <- gsub("\"", "", paste0(lst, collapse = " & "))
                print(txt)

                subset(mtcars, eval(expr = parse(text = txt) ) )

            })
        }
    )
)
```